# Weird XmlMixed XML <-> JAXB <-> JSON marshalling/unmarshalling with MOXy

Tags: jaxb, moxy

I have following type, defined in schema as:

```
<xsd:complexType name="any_t" mixed="true">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:any>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Generated JAXB class:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "any_t", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
public class AnyT implements Serializable
{
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> content;
    public List<Object> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

Some JAXB class that uses this type:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "addInfo"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "FORM_OF_COOWNERS")
public class FormOfCoowners
    implements Serializable
{
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "add_info")
    protected AnyT addInfo;
    public AnyT getAddInfo() { return addInfo; }
    public void setAddInfo(AnyT value) { this.addInfo = value; }
}
```

When I unmarshall this XML to JAXB object:

```
<FORM_OF_COOWNERS>
   <add_info>
      <info_analytics>
         <issuer_subdiv>
            <id><id>1940001</id></id>
         </issuer_subdiv>
         <fl_worker>Yes</fl_worker>
      </info_analytics>
   </add_info>
</FORM_OF_COOWNERS>
```

and marshall this object to JSON, I get:

```
{"FORM_OF_COOWNERS":{"add_info":{"info_analytics":[{"issuer_subdiv":{"id":{"id":"1940001"}},"fl_worker":"Yes"}]}}}
```

where does this list came from? info_analytics maps to a type without any collections/arrays.

If I get this JSON, umarshall it to JAXB object and marshall to XML, it produces:

```
<info_analytics fl_worker="Yes">
  <issuer_subdiv>
    <id id="1940001">
       <id>1940001</id>
    </id>
  </issuer_subdiv>
  <fl_worker>Yes</fl_worker>
</info_analytics>
```

why elements are duplicated as attributes?

**UPDATE**: marshalling/unmarshalling to/from json:

```scala
def unmarshallToJaxbTyped[A : ClassTag](json: String): Throwable \/ A =
  \/.fromTryCatchNonFatal {
    val cls = classTag[A].runtimeClass
    val jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(cls)
    val unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller()
    unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json")
    unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(json)), cls)
      .getValue.asInstanceOf[A]
  }

def marshallJaxbToJson(obj: Any): Throwable \/ String =
  \/.fromTryCatchNonFatal {
    val jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass)
    val marshaller = jc.createMarshaller()
    marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json")
    val writer = new StringWriter()
    marshaller.marshal(obj, writer)
    writer.getBuffer.toString
  }
```

xml:

```xml
protected static synchronized JAXBContext getContext() {
  if (jaxbContext == null)
    try {
      jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.example.models");
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  return jaxbContext;
}

public static void saveMessage(Object msg, OutputStream os) throws JAXBException {
  Marshaller marshaller = getContext().createMarshaller();
  marshaller.marshal(msg, os);
}

public static Object loadMessage(InputStream is) throws JAXBException {
  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = getContext().createUnmarshaller();
  return unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details? (e.g. marshal and unmarshal code, creation object, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how ofter such weird roundtrip: XML -> Java -> JSON -> Java -> XML is needed. I think you understand, that XML supports much more features than JSON and that's why it's not always possible to have 1 to 1 mapping.

If this is a real problem for you and not only theoretical investigations please fire a bug against MOXy: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink

Comment: It's purely practical investigation. As workaround I ended up writing some more strongly typed class and adapter from this class to/from AnyT